# LC4 Assembly instructions

Tags: assembly

I am trying to convert this pseudocode into LC4 assembly language

```
B = 0
If (A >= 0) {
   While (B*B <= A) {
   B = B + 1
   }
}
B = B - 1
```

What mnemonic do I use for an if statement? Would it be CMP and for the while statement CMPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's the other way around, the `if` compares against a constant, while the `while` does not. So use `cmpi` to compare `A` against `0` and `cmp` to compare `B*B` against `A`.

Comment: If the input is negative, the output should be -1. What instruction would I use for this?

Comment: You still can compare against 0, as negative numbers are less than 0.